# Texel offsets in pixel shaders

Tags: image, glsl, windows-phone-8, hlsl

I am currently porting an app over from iOS to Windows Phone 8. It is an image processing app, and all calculations are done on the GPU using pixel shaders.

There is one detail that I just haven't been able to figure out, that is Texel Width/Height offsets. I have absolutely no idea what these values are, and I can't seem to find any information on them.

Are they common terms? Does anybody know what they represent? Does anyone know what sort of values should be in them?

Comment: See wikipedia for the definition of Texel: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texel_%28graphics%29.  Maybe add some code or structures or API definitions to show context on the width/height calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Texel is a pixel of texture localized by a coordinate, the offset in a texture is where a texture begin mapped on a model or render target.

The most simple example of this:
http://lifeasa.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/super_mario_world_by_xinzax.png
The map of stage is a few textures, when Mario advances in level, the X coordinate offset increases, and the right part of texture became visible, at same time the left side becames hidden.

Check the textures, if have more than a 'part' in a single image, is this.

Another case is a single texture that is mapped in multiple objects, and each object have a offset to appears a 'segment' of previous object.

Comment: Sound like I don't even need the offset...wierd